# How to parallel two or more functions

Tags: r

If I have two or more functions with different parameters,how can I make them parallel?
Please give me an example that is not too complicated.

I only know how to parallel single function.

```
 test <- function(x) {
     for (i in 1:10000000) {
         x <- x + i
     }
     return(x)
 }
 library(snow)
 cl <- makeCluster(type = "SOCK", c("localhost", "localhost"))  # 建立两个本地CPU内核的并行
 system.time({test(5);test(5)})
用户 系统 流逝 
0.58 0.00 0.58 
 system.time(clusterCall(cl, test,5)) # 测试并行循环的耗时
用户 系统 流逝 
0.00 0.00 0.37
```

Comment: Please set the comments and/or output to English so people can understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using library `foreach`?

First install `foreach` and `doParallel`

```
install.packages('foreach')
install.packages('doParallel')
```

And i edited your code a litte .

```
test1 <- function(x) {
 for (i in 1:10000000) {
 x <- x + i
 }
 return(x)
}
library(snow)
cl <- makeCluster(type = "SOCK", c("localhost", "localhost")) 
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
```

If you have functions like `test1, test2, test3, ...`

After `registerDoParallel`, you can use any another function you want like below.

```
foreach::foreach(i=1:2) %dopar% {
test1(x)
test2(x)
test3(x)
...
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me the meaning of the parameter "i = 1:2" of foreach function?

Comment: `i` means iteration it is same as `for(i in 1:2)`. For example, if i set `i=1:4`. So `i=1` will be allocate `cluster 1` and  `i=2` will be allocated `cluster 2`. After finish one job, `i=3` will be allocate `cluster 1` (assume `i=1`  finished earlier) ..